# Xcode 8 Storyboard - Updating existing storyboards. App republish required?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, storyboard, ios10

I just updated to `Xcode 8`. On selecting any of the devices at bottom, constraints are to be reset. Since the view is now not accommodating on the screens. Earlier to this, I was using **wAny hAny** window and also supplied the constraints. These constrains are even there now but need to be changed.
I am assuming the only way I see is to update the frames and constraints for all devices (wondering it is a boon or curse). But since a single constraint will be same for all devices, how will it's value be retained considering it has to be used in code.
How to update the existing storyboards to fit `Xcode 8` ?
Having said this, storyboard needs to be restructured which means app needs to be published again as the current build would give layout issues on `iOS 10`.
Is my reason valid enough ?

Comment: @maddy : Apple tag was to let apple check this. I am adding the tag again. Please state the reason you want to remove it.

Comment: Read the description of the apple tag. It says "DO NOT USE".

Comment: Disappointing. If it is not to be used, what's the purpose.

Comment: Given that this is not an Apple forum, it is unlikely that any Apple employee is monitoring questions to provide answers.  With that sad, tagging something as "Apple" is way too broad aad not descriptive for the issue at hand as it could apply to multiple devices and multiple operating systems.

Comment: @Nitish have a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/39495889/2522603

Comment: @Imran : The solution says update the frame for each UIViewController. I have 20+ apps and each of app has at least 15-20 screens. And I am just one ideal dev. A  dev might have n number of apps. This might be the temporary and tedious, well quite tedious solution, but isn't really a solution. Thanks for the reference though.

Comment: @Nitish i just said what makes me done for my app, you can 15 or 1000, as per this scenario i guess my is the best, else u have to specifically write to apple developer for getting everything automatically done.

Comment: @Imran : Sure I agree with you. But for that matter, I had already mentioned this in my question :)

Comment: @Nitish i don't think so, your voice will reach to apple people from here, because here all are developers and they would specifically suggest you what have worked them to get it done. that too i did, but u need a generic solution, so u have to get attention from apple guys

Comment: @Imran : You are right. Will create bug on bug reporter. I have also asked this on apple dev forum. https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/179611#179611

Comment: @Nitish it's good, hope you will get generic answer there and will update here too once u get any feedback email from apple dev's.

Answer (score 13):

I am not sure I understand your question, but I ran into a situation that I think may have been similar. After upgrading a project to Xcode 8 my storyboards did not appear to have the correct constraints obeyed. Everything would still work when I compiled and tested, but Xcode storyboards would look all wrong.

In addition to this, Xcode presented a whole bunch of warnings that "Frame for XYZ will be different at run time."

I found that I could click in the small yellow warning arrow next to the scene in the structure pane and then click on the small yellow warning icon next to one of the misplaced views. From the popup I selected `Update frames` and `Apply to all views in this container` and then I clicked the `Fix misplacements` button.

This seemed to clean up the storyboard and remove all the warnings.

Comment: On running the project on latest Xcode, all screens are distorted with the same old code. That means, frames and constraints need to be updated.

Comment: The `Apply to all views in this container` saved me a lot of time, thanks!