# Xcode 8 autolayout has ruined my project

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

The new Xcode 8 update to use trait variations has resulted in all of my storyboard view controllers losing their autolayout integrity. It was all previously set out on the interface builder in the regular width | regular height setting (that "one size fits all" square you get by default when you make a new project). But it's now been changed to represent an iPhone 6.

I want to be able to change it back to the way it was before, but the "use size classes" checkbox has been removed and replaced with "use trait variations".

Comment: @Matt Spoon , if you were using auto layout, have  a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/39495889/2522603

Comment: I upvoted your question just for the title.  Thanks for that, because I feel the same way.  If only I didn't have 100k users using my app right now...

Comment: You guys ever think about source control or backups?

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar issue. The solution here works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39589860/1751266

Basically revert your storyboard back to the XCode 7 format. Unfortunately you have to do it every time you make a change to the storyboard :/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After trying all the solutions proposed in the link provided by `CMash` the only solution that worked for me was installing `Xcode 7` and compile my project with it.

Of course that's a quick workaround which should not be the definitive answer, but for an urgent case it might work (like mine, I had 1 day to test and send the app to my customer).